# Laravel 6 with function not showing related data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've made a really simple function in Laravel 6 that uses with():

```
$forms = Form::with('itemsForms')->get();

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 200,
            'data' => $forms
        ]);
```

The following are the relationships between Form and ItemsForm:

```
//Form
protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'subtitle',
        'text',
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'address',
        'board',
        'date',
        'file',
        'purchasable',
        'payment_for',
        'invoice_amount',
    ];

protected $visible = [
        'title',
        'subtitle',
        'text',
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'address',
        'board',
        'date',
        'file',
        'purchasable',
        'payment_for',
        'invoice_amount',
    ];

public function itemsForms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemsForm');
    }
```

```
//ItemsForm
protected $fillable = [
        'item_id', 'form_id'
    ];

public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form', 'form_id');
    }
```

The thing is it doesn't retrieve any data from ItemsForm.
Here's some of what I've tried:

- I tried changing parameter in `with` to other similar names but in each case I got an error of "relationship not found" or something like that. When I use `itemsForms` I get no error.
- I tried debugging it enabling the query log. Here's what I got:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `forms`"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 5.77
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `items_forms` where `items_forms`.`form_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 1.03
  ]
]
```

- I tried getting the `ItemsForm` data and it retrieves it with no issue (`ItemsForm::all()`).

Any idea of what could be causing this?

**Edit**: the schema for ItemsForm is the following:

```
Schema::create('items_forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('item_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('form_id');
            $table->foreign('item_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('items')
                  ->onDelete('no action')
                  ->onUpdate('no action');
            $table->foreign('form_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('forms')
                  ->onDelete('no action')
                  ->onUpdate('no action');
        });
```

Comment: Can you show the schema for `items_forms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what the issue was.

The issue was I didn't include `itemsForms` in the `visible` array (even though it is not part of the database fields).

There was no particular reason to include the `visible` array in my case so I deleted it but if I had wanted to keep it I should have included `itemsForms` as an element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Change the relationship as follows..
In Form class

```
public function itemsForms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ItemsForm','form_id','id');
}
```

In ItemsForm

```
public function form()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Form', 'id','form_id');
}
```

You can use the relationship as

```
 $res = Form::find($id);
 foreach($res->itemsForms as $item)
 {
  echo $item->item_id;
 }
```

Comment: put a `dd($res->itemsForms)` to see whether you got the results or not